# Building two different builds for two different MCUs into one binary blob in one yocto project

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

We have two different MCUs on our system. The primary one runs an OS that controls the whole system, and the secondary one runs a small task on bare metal.

The secondary has no flash, so when the system starts, it will ask the primary for a program, which the primary will feed it from the primary's flash.

This all works fine, but we have 2 Yocto builds to build each of these, and we have to feed the secondary's software as a built binary blob to the primary's Yocto build.

Is there a way to get one Yocto project to build both, without us having to manually run one build, then the other?

Comment: While you are asking advice to compile both of your targets on Yocto, my feeling is that it's not really the task of Yocto to build a small firmware for bare metal.

It can be done this way as you prove it but Yocto is quite complex and excels to build complex target with a lot of dependencies for example.

Is there any good reason to build this firmware with Yocto ?

Comment: You are completely right, we have a (forgive me) make or cmake build for the bare metal chip that we run first, and the problem is how to get that under yocto, rather than passing it a binary blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yocto is definitely not the tool you are looking for from my point of view.

What you need is more a `CI/CD platform` like Gitlab which contains the project for the MCU. On each commit (or depending on your build policy) the project is built and binary is pushed to a web server then you Yocto can have a git based version recipe which can download the resulting binary.

Alternatively, your CI can also manage the Yocto project and start the build triggered by the MCU firmware project.

This is something common in embedded system to use directly binary instead of sources, e.g. the Linux kernel can embed binary blob for coprocessor but that's clearly not the job of Yocto to handle dependencies between multiple architecture types.

Comment: Someone on the team suggested something similar, so we're reassured that someone else came to the same conclusion. Thank you.